# Configuring Wildfly standalone.xml in Galleon feature-pack

Tags: wildfly

I'm working on a POC for a Galleon feature-pack providing the [Camunda BPM subsystem](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/tree/master/distro/wildfly/subsystem).

My current progress can be found here: https://github.com/marcus-nl/camunda-galleon-pack

[This article](https://wildfly.org/news/2019/12/17/Ship-your-WildFly-additions-via-Galleon-feature-packs/) and the linked example/template have been very helpful thus far, but unfortunately I'm stuck at a point which these don't quite cover: customizing the standalone.xml configuration.

The required additions to standalone.xml are as follows: [standalone.xml](https://gist.github.com/marcus-nl/3dc61f34f2f37f4366ea1310865046e2#file-1_standalone-xml). So basically there are 4 additions:

1. The Camunda BPM extension and subsystem. This was no problem.
2. The H2 driver and Camunda datasource. The wildfly-datasources-galleon-pack was very helpful for this.
3. A job-executor configuration.
4. A process-engine configuration.

I can not figure out how to achieve 3 and 4. Starting with 3, the CLI command to simply add the job-executor (without a nested job-acquisitions element) is as follows:

```
/subsystem=camunda-bpm-platform/job-executor=job-executor:add(core-threads=3, max-threads=5, queue-length=10)
```

After some experimentation I came to the following feature spec (see [camunda-subsystem.xml](https://github.com/marcus-nl/camunda-galleon-pack/blob/master/galleon-pack/src/main/resources/feature_groups/camunda-subsystem.xml)):

```
<feature spec="subsystem.camunda-bpm-platform">
  <param name="subsystem" value="subsystem.camunda-bpm-platform"/>
  <feature spec="subsystem.camunda-bpm-platform.job-executor">
    <param name="job-executor" value="default"/>
    <param name="core-threads" value="3"/>
    <param name="max-threads"  value="5"/>
    <param name="queue-length" value="10"/>
  </feature>
</feature>
```

Leading to the error message:

> Failed to build configuration  model standalone named standalone.xml:
>   Failed to resolve feature reference subsystem.camunda-bpm-platform for
>   {com.github.marcus-nl.camunda-galleon}subsystem.camunda-bpm-platform.job-executor:
>   Foreign key parameter host of
>   {com.github.marcus-nl.camunda-galleon}subsystem.camunda-bpm-platform.job-executor
>   reference subsystem.camunda-bpm-platform does not exist

I am stuck there. IIUC this has to do with the parent-child relationship between the camunda-bpm-platform element and the job-executor element. The "foreign key parameter host" seems to refer to the "host" param in [the generated spec.xml for camunda-bpm-platform](https://gist.github.com/marcus-nl/3dc61f34f2f37f4366ea1310865046e2#file-2_camunda-bpm-platform_spec-xml) ([this is the one for job-executor btw](https://gist.github.com/marcus-nl/3dc61f34f2f37f4366ea1310865046e2#file-3_job-executor_spec-xml)), but if I try to define it as follows:

```
<feature spec="subsystem.camunda-bpm-platform">
  <param name="host" value="subsystem.camunda-bpm-platform"/>
  <param name="subsystem" value="subsystem.camunda-bpm-platform"/>
```

I get the error "Feature spec subsystem.camunda-bpm-platform.job-executor does not define parameter host", even though (as you can see) I defined the param in the parent "camunda-bpm-platform", not the "job-executor" child.

What am I missing here? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It seems to me that if you define a host in your subsystem then it becomes part of the address thus you have to define it in your sub-elements.

Comment: Are you generating for host and domain also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you ran into a bug in galleon. We are investigating it. For now you can workaround the problem by generating the features for domain as done in: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/galleon-pack/wildfly-feature-pack-build.xml#L89

Thank-you.

Comment: Generating for domain as well did the trick. Thank you!

For anyone else running into this issue, [this Wildfly forum topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wildfly/m1WO5pCIXQw) has more background information.